# For loop - iterate from 1 to x

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.4

I have loop in Twig template:

```
{% for item in 1..0 %}
     {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

(of course in real life instead of 0 there is variable value). I would expect in this example that loop won't be executed because 0 is lower than 1. But in fact it displays

```
1 0
```

**Question**: is there any way in this example using simple for loop in Twig (or other loop) to tell Twig I want to iterate ++ not -- or I have to add condition to check before loop if 0 is lower than 1

**EDIT**:

**Of course I'm aware I can create array in PHP and use it in Twig template but what about this case - without creating array in PHP**

**EDIT2**:

I want it simple use for generating star rating. Now I need to have code because I had to add extra if checking for each for loop:

```
{%  if full_stars_number >= 1 %}
    {%  for item in 1..full_stars_number %}
       <img src="img/full_star.png" />
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{%  if half_stars_number >= 1 %}
    {%  for item in 1..half_stars_number %}
       <img src="img/half_star.png" />
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{%  if empty_stars_number >= 1 %}
    {%  for item in 1..empty_stars_number %}
       <img src="img/empty_star.png" />
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: see this http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition

Comment: I read it before asking this question but I think it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I think because the twig is not a programming language and is just for templating, the only option is @Blacksad answer; What I understood from loop in twig it works as `foreach` not simple `for`; even if you want to set a specific step you need to define `range` with your step then put in the `for`

Comment: As I see using range in for in Twig also won't work because range(1,0,1) return element 1 and 0 not empty array. I know that Twig is template engine but such simple function as iterating from 1 to x as in PHP should be by default as in other template engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{%  for item in 1..full_stars_number if full_stars_number>0 %}
   <img src="img/full_star.png" />
{% endfor %}

{%  for item in 1..half_stars_number if half_stars_number>0 %}
   <img src="img/half_star.png" />
{% endfor %}

{%  for item in 1..empty_stars_number if empty_stars_number>0 %}
   <img src="img/empty_star.png" />
{% endfor %}
```

This is basically the same as what you already did in your EDIT2, but in a slightly more concise way.

Comment: I think that will be the best option in this case

Comment: Just bare in mind that this actually iterates through all the elements. So, if `full_stars_number` is zero it will iterate through 1 and 0. The if condition is run for each of the items.

Comment: No! if the condition is false (i.e. `full_stars_number<=0`) the code inside the `for` is not executed, otherwise what would be the use of the possibility to add a condition?

Answer (score 1):

`1..x` generates a collection, with inclusive values. It can be ordered ascending or descending. This is expected.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but the way you described it is not possible in twig out of the box.

You could write your own [twig function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions), which would generate the values, or return an empty array:

```
{% set itemsCount = 0 %}
{% for item in my_crazy_function(itemsCount) %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Edit:

If you simply want to repeat a value number of times you could write a twig filter:

```
{{ '<img src="img/empty_star.png" />' | repeat(5) }}
```

A function implementation could just be a call to PHP's [str_repeat](http://php.net/str_repeat):

```php
class Project_Twig_Extension extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFilter('repeat', 'str_repeat'),
        );
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can simple do that but what about 1..x syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. Updated the answer.

Comment: I posted in question code that shows what I want achieve